# how to read a .bib file as text and separate it's field for bibliometric goals?

Tags: matlab

i have a .bib file and i am using MATLAB to extract different fields from it. the goal is to calculate different bibliometric indexes like h-index.
i have tried textscan() but because the fields are not same for every article it did not all the job.
the bib is as follows:

```
@article{LIM20072054,
title = "Prevention of cardiovascular disease in high-risk individuals in low-income and middle-income countries: health effects and costs",
journal = "The Lancet",
volume = "370",
number = "9604",
pages = "2054 - 2062",
year = "2007",
issn = "0140-6736",
doi = "https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(07)61699-7",
url = "http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140673607616997",
author = "Stephen S Lim and Thomas A Gaziano and Emmanuela Gakidou and K Srinath Reddy and Farshad Farzadfar and Rafael Lozano and Anthony Rodgers",
abstract = "Summary}
```

i tried fgetl() to get lines but i need to read all the file at once and maybe fine { with } to seperate articles, does anybody have a better idea how to extract an unformatted text with different field while we know the field names?
this is the first code

```
a = fopen('C:\Users\u3f\Downloads\a.bib');
textI='@article{%s title = %q %*s %*s %*s %*s year = %q %*s %*s %*s %*s abstract = %q %*s';
C = textscan(a,textI,'Delimiter','\n')
fclose(a)
```

Comment: You need to write a parser. BibTeX is a language, just like MATLAB, C, XML, etc. Parsers use knowledge of the grammar of a language to interpret text.

Answer (score 1):

This might need a little bit of work, but should get you what you want.

The idea is to scan line by line, first looking for a line that starts with `@article{`. Then it creates a block and adds the following lines until one that ends with `}` is found (note that if your bibtex has fields that end with `}` it might need some modification).

When the end of a block is found, it is converted into an structure, where each entry on the bibtex becomes a field. They keyword of the entry is also added as a field called `name`. After all blocks are processed you will have a cell called `entryList` with one structure per bibtex entry.

Keep in mind that for complex entries you might need to do much more complex text parsing to get everything working.

```
a = fopen('a.bib');
insideEntry = false;
currEntry = {};
entryList = {};
while(~feof(a))
  lin = fgetl(a); % Pull one line at a time
  if(insideEntry) % If you are inside an @article block
    currEntry = [currEntry lin]; % Append line
    if(regexp(lin, '$*}')) % Check for the end of a block
      insideEntry = false;
      entryname = extractBetween(currEntry{1}, '@article{',',');
      entryStruct = struct;
      entryStruct.name = entryname{1};
      for it = 2:length(currEntry)
        sepLine = strsplit(currEntry{it}, '=');
        if(length(sepLine) == 2)
          fieldName = strrep(strtrim(sepLine{1}),'-','_'); % Fix the keyword name (so it can be a field in a structure)
          sepLine{2} = regexprep(sepLine{2},'$*[",}]',''); % Fix end of entry
          sepLine{2} = regexprep(sepLine{2},'^[ "{]',''); % Fix start of entry
          entryStruct.(fieldName) = sepLine{2}; % Assign text to the struct field
        end
      end
      entryList{end+1} = entryStruct; % Append to the entry list
      currEntry = {};
    end
  elseif(contains(lin, '@article{')) % Look for @article block start line
    insideEntry = true;
    currEntry = [currEntry lin];
  end
end
fclose(a);
```

For the sample bibtex you gave this should produce:

```
entryList{1}

ans = 

struct with fields:

    name: 'LIM20072054'
   title: 'Prevention of cardiovascular disease in high-risk individuals in low-income and middle-income countries: health effects and costs'
 journal: 'The Lancet'
  volume: '370'
  number: '9604'
   pages: '2054 - 2062'
    year: '2007'
    issn: '0140-6736'
     doi: 'https://doi.org/10.1016/S0140-6736(07)61699-7'
     url: 'http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0140673607616997'
  author: 'Stephen S Lim and Thomas A Gaziano and Emmanuela Gakidou and K Srinath Reddy and Farshad Farzadfar and Rafael Lozano and Anthony Rodgers'
abstract: 'Summary'
```

Comment: Nice first pass at a parser. This probably still needs a lot of work to make it generic enough to parse arbitrary BibTeX, for example where you look for `'@article{'`, you should probably look for any of the 15 or so known types of entry, or make it generic to accept any token after the `@`.

Comment: which version of MATLAB are you using? mine is 2014a and it throws an error on  contains and extractbetween functions

Comment: They were introduced in 2016b. You could use strcmp strfind and/or regexprep to obtain the same functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can use a BibTeX parsing library to read the file for you and turn it in to data structures. That way you don't have to do the low-level parsing of those files yourself using the basic I/O functions that Matlab provides for file formats it doesn't have built-in support for.

Matlab can use Java libraries, so you could use the [jbibtex library](https://github.com/jbibtex/jbibtex).

(And here's [details on how to call Java libraries from Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/using-java-libraries-in-matlab.html).)

Comment: this is a great solution, i can use java libraries in Matlab, but is there a way to install java libraries from Matlab, without using a java IDE like Eclipse?

Comment: Yep. Not directly using Matlab code, but you can do it manually. Just download the JAR files, save them somewhere in your source tree (I like "lib/java/<libname>-<version>/whatever.jar"), and use Matlab's `javaaddpath()` function to add the JAR files to the Matlab Java classpath. (If there's a bunch of them, write a little function that will find "lib/java/*/*.jar" and add call `javaaddpath()` on all of them.) Alternately, you could use Maven's `mvn install dependency:copy-dependencies` to grab all the JARs at once.